# Merge and filter javascript object/array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take an object containing other objects and filter them first. Then if any objects contain the same two key/value pairs, I want to merge them to add any new data.

I know how to use the spread operator to merge the two, but I can not for the life of figure out the filter method.

Here is a sample object structure:

```
let timesheet = {
         'job1': {
                   day_of_week: 1,
                   wo_number: '486322',
                   reg_hours: 4.5
                 }


          'job2': {
                   day_of_week: 1,
                   wo_number: '486322',
                   ot_hours: 2.0
                 }


           'job3': {
                   day_of_week: 1,
                   wo_number: '486922',
                   reg_hours: 3.5
                 }


        }
```

What I am doing is that I take the info from a db call, turn it into JSON and then re-create the object with meaningful keys I can use. Then I delete all the keys I don't need. I am left with an object similar to the above sample, except with many other keys.

What I need to do is filter through these. Any job# that matches both wo_number and day_of_week numbers are to be considered the same job. Those will then be merged and the properties reg_hours and ot_hours will be then on the same job# and the other job# will not be returned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to lack information. Like what your data looks like, what you have done and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are formatting this data after the query so for the solution below I used a different key value (a composite of WO number and day of the week). If this does not work for your use case just let me know and I can refactor the function a bit. Here is the approach that I could come up with, hope it can help:

```js
function mergeJobs(timeSheet) {
  const result = {};

  for (const [_, jobData] of Object.entries(timeSheet)) {
    const { wo_number, day_of_week } = jobData

    const jobKey = `${wo_number}-${day_of_week}`;

    if (result[jobKey]) {
      result[jobKey] = {
        ...result[jobKey],
        ...jobData,
      };
    } else {
      result[jobKey] = jobData;
    }
  }

  return result;
}


let timeSheet = {
  job1: {
    day_of_week: 1,
    wo_number: "486322",
    reg_hours: 4.5,
  },

  job2: {
    day_of_week: 1,
    wo_number: "486322",
    ot_hours: 2.0,
  },

  job3: {
    day_of_week: 1,
    wo_number: "486922",
    reg_hours: 3.5,
  },
};

console.log(mergeJobs(timeSheet));
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to PCDSandwichMan's answer except this creates meaningful keys during the destructuring operation by relabelling the object properties, and finally outputs an array of objects which may be easier to handle in the long-run

```js
const timesheet={job1:{day_of_week:1,wo_number:"486322",reg_hours:4.5},job2:{day_of_week:1,wo_number:"486322",ot_hours:2},job3:{day_of_week:1,wo_number:"486922",reg_hours:3.5}};

// Temporary object to hold the updated data
const temp = {};

// Iterate over the timesheet object's values
// ie the nested objects
for (const obj of Object.values(timesheet)) {
 
  // For each object destructure and relabel the
  // properties so they're a little more meaningful
  const {
    day_of_week: weekday,
    wo_number: orderId,
    reg_hours: hours,
    ot_hours: overtime
  } = obj;

  // Create a jobId using the number of jobs currently
  // in the temp object. Initially this will be 0 (no keys)
  // so the first jobId will be 1
  const jobId = Object.keys(temp).length + 1;

  // Create a key that we can use as a lookup on temp
  // using the orderId and weekday values
  // within a template string
  const key = `${orderId}-${weekday}`;
  
  // If the key doesn't already exist on the temp object
  // assign it a new object with all the old properties, plus
  // the jobId, and initialse the hours/overtime values to 0
  // You can just remove the properties you don't want appearing
  // in the final structure at this point.
  temp[key] ??= {
    jobId,
    orderId,
    weekday,
    hours: 0,
    overtime: 0
  };
  
  // Update the hours/overtime values with the values
  // from the current object
  if (hours) temp[key].hours += hours;
  if (overtime) temp[key].overtime += overtime;

}

// Finally grab the values from the temp object
// to give you an array of objects
// which will probably be easier to manage
console.log(Object.values(temp));
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)